# How to insert the record with MySQL NOW() function in MySQLi with bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to execute this mysql query in MySQLi PDO with bind parametr in PHP:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` (post_name,publish_date) VALUES ($post_name,NOW()) ")
```

I use the script like this, but it doesn't insert publish_date correctly.

```
$publish_date = 'NOW()';
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_name,publish_date) VALUES (?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ss", $post_name $publish_date);
$insert->execute();
```

It inserts the record into the `publish_date` column like this: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`
How can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

P.S: The type of date column is `datatime`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not a parameter of the query, in that you don't have to supply a value to MySQL.

```
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_name, publish_date) VALUES (?, NOW())");
```

Comment: Additionally: The reason you are ending up with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` inserted is that you are trying to insert the string `'NOW()'` rather than a recognisable datetime value. MySQL coerces the string to a datetime value, and the value it chooses is the zero date.

Comment: But ... and the variable in bind_param to supply "NOW()" in bind_param?

Comment: @Pedro, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in bind_param, a value will supply the first '?'. Is not necessary a value to supply the second param (NOW())?

Comment: One of the parameters should be deleted from the call to bind_param(). There's only one "?", so only one parameter ($post_name).

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should try using the date function  not NOW()

```
$publish_date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post_name,publish_date) VALUES (?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ss", $post_name $publish_date);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the database and the php do not run on the same server, the clocks might not be in sync. This means that NOW() (which takes the time from the database server) and date (which takes the time from the php/webserver) are not the same. I ran into several problems because of this issue. A solution would be to s sync all times by using ntp.

Comment: @theomega had not seen that one if the database and php/webserver were on  different servers using ntp time synchronization script will solve the issue