# How to update field using bind_param and MySQL NOW () function in Structured PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the edit date of a user's data using MySQL's `NOW()` function and prepared statements. The code looks like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE admins 
        SET user = ?, name = ?, edit_date = NOW() 
        WHERE id_admin = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $user, $name, $id_admin);
```

This is the way it is in the tutorial I'm following. Obviously it is a very simple code to understand. But I can't get the `NOW()` value to be saved to the database. In the table the data type is datetime, but it is always kept in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format.

I am missing a parameter in the bind_param? or what is the reason?

I have tried this method, but it didn't work:
[How to insert the record with MySQL NOW() function in MySQLi with bind_param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497186/how-to-insert-the-record-with-mysql-now-function-in-mysqli-with-bind-param)

I appreciate your support, this is my first question, greetings to all.

Comment: That statement looks like it should work. Are you sure there isn't something else modifying the `edit_date` column?

Comment: Instead of updating the `edit_date` in your PHP code, you could declare it as `TIMESTAMP` with the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option. Then it will be updated to the current time whenever any other column is modified.

Comment: Hello @Barmar , thanks for responding. It actually works by declaring the field as a `TIMESTAMP` type, with the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` . But I'm very curious why it doesn't work with the `NOW()` function. As you say, the code should work as I am declaring it. If you have any idea I would appreciate it if you share it. All the best.

Comment: What you've written has to work. So either you haven't copied the code correctly, you're not checking the results correctly, or something else is changing it.